# Strange faulty 16000d response timing in gdevtools for specific XHR

Tags: networking, nginx, http-headers, ajax

We have some XHR on our website, that is reported in Google developer tools' network timeline as Receiving for 16035.5 days. There actually is a response, and for sure it does not take as long as reported ;)

I reviewed the HTTP headers and to me everything looks fine. That problem is not occurring temporarily but consistently for the same XHR. What's even more strange: If I do the same GET directly instead of using AJAX, the timing is reported correctly.

What could be the reason for this? I suspect some faulty response, but I can not see anything not normal.

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers:

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: [...snip...]
Host: [...snip...]
Referer: [...snip...]
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest



Response Headers:

Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 09 Dec 2013 06:22:30 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Server:web01
```